# Modifying received sms on android

Tags: android, sms

I'm writing an app, which needs to interrupt sms incoming event and then modify sms body. User must get modified message, not original. Interrupting sms event is too simple with BroadcastReceiver here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        //this.abortBroadcast(); // stop notification to user
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String sender = "";
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); // PDU - "protocol description unit", which is the industry format for an SMS message
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                // large message might be broken into many
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    System.out.println("Msg Body: " + msgBody + " From: " + sender);
                    /// I need to modify msgBody
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }            

    }

}
```

But I can't change message body. Is there any way to do this?
If not, is there any way to create this sms in inbox on my own and send the notification to user?

Comment: check this out:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894301/intercept-incoming-sms-message-and-modify-it

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is to register a receiver with highest priority, so when your receiver picks up an incoming sms perform abortBroadcast(), this will make sure other application in line for processing dont receive it to ruin your changes.

taking it further, you can query SMS database with the latest received sms find row_id of this entry in table, thats it, it is now trimmed down to an update query for modifying text.

this might require in system app permission in few cases, in that scenario you device need to be rooted.