# How to abort sms from hangout

Tags: android

I search so much for sms filter for hangout enabled android phones where I only found that this is not possible.

But there is one app as sms filter by Tsvetan Nachev which blocks sms from hangout and link for this app is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nachev.apps.smsfilter

I tested on 4.1.2

So anybody know how does that happening in that app?

here is my code

```
  if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) 
  {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) 
{
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    if (pdus.length == 0) 
    {
        return;
    }

    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
    {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
    }
    String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
    String message = sb.toString();

    if(message.equals("something"))
    {
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You May look at this-[Intercept Incoming SMS Message and Modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894301/intercept-incoming-sms-message-and-modify-it/17182974#17182974) What you need to do is check `when message is came from hangout application it it contains in address or subject that is diff` from other message format.For `message abort` may look the  `abortBroadcast(); method` inside `broadcast message receiver` in android that receives intent for incoming message.Hope this Helps you.

Comment: My question is how i can filter any incoming message no matter from where it sent, So when i tried ur suggested answer i still have same issue as my normal sms inbox not showing sms but hangout is showing same message so how can I abort this message?

Comment: the link you given just block incoming message from sender that are stored in sqlite db of app.when incoming message come within  receiver it check whether number is from black list number if yes that call abortbraodcast(); method so that that messge will not deliver to mobile inbox

Comment: which ever messge will come you need to store into the  sqlite db locally within your app then this you can make phone number as primary key in your db table so that you will get all message of particular sender.Hope this helps to understand db things for your requirement

Comment: Yeah i know but hangout is now my default inbox so how can i bock message from hangout. I tried every possible way but still i'm having same problem n also i set priority of my SmsReceiver to highest(1000,999,2147483647)

Comment: paste your code what is happing and what expected as your question is not clear.better to have code with snapshot for clarification

Comment: you are not clear with your requirement buddy whatever you have given doesnt clarify anything.sorry but with this i cant able to help you.