# Android : sms receiver is not working

Tags: java, android, sms, toast

I am writing an sms receiver android code but it is not working.
It compiles will but when I get an sms it did not displayed as supposed to be when using Toast.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.homecontrolingbysms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String messageReceived = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
           Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);  
                messageReceived +="From "+ msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                messageReceived+=" : ";
                messageReceived += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                messageReceived += "\n";        
            }

            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, messageReceived, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                         
    }
}
```

I also posted manifest to make sure all important parts of code are available 
manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.homecontrolingbysms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.homecontrolingbysms.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name="com.example.homecontrolingbysms.Door"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.homecontrolingbysms.Window"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.homecontrolingbysms.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what are your intent-filters in manifest?

Comment: Do you have permissions in manifest file?

Comment: Have you register the BroadcastReceiver(SmsReceiver) in the android-manifest.xml file?

Comment: @Zeel i'll update my code now by posting the manifets file

Comment: @mohammad post your manifest file..

Comment: Where did you register SmsReceiver? In code?

Answer (score 2):

Register smsreceiver by adding below code in menifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.shreymalhotra.smsreceiver.SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This links may help you.

[Receiving SMS on Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app)

http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/receive-sms-using-android-broadcastreceiver-inside-an-activity/

Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your manifest looks okay; the problem is with the line:
Mistake is in this part I think can you change this

```
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String messageReceived = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
```

to something like this

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());
    intent.getAction().equals(ACTION) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
```

(you need to do an object comparison on the action string, or just do no comparison), in your manifest file you have misspelled SMS_RECEIVED.

Comment: why ? any reason in particular ?

Comment: @njzk2 sorry but i did not understood ?

Comment: you need to do an object comparison on the action string

Answer (score 0):

if you want to receive some broadcasts , blew things must be done.
1. In the manifest.xml ,you must declare your receiver with the intent filter 
    exp:
            
            
                
           
2. if the broadcast that you want to receive is ordered, you must make sure your priority.
         android:priority="1000"