# Auto reply SMS with onReceive

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-context

I currently have a method that i want to use which is OnReceive

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String senderNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    String message = "";

    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
            senderNumber = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
        senderNumber = msgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        sendMessage(senderNumber, "Thank you for sending me a message");
    }
}
```

And i want to use this method in this class, but I am not sure what to put in the brackets when calling the method.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


private GoogleMap mMap;
 IncomingSMSReceiver receiver = new IncomingSMSReceiver();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    receiver.onReceive();
```

Can someone help me with telling me what to put in the onReceive() brackets?

EDIT

I did what you said and changed my codes, I also did not call the onReceive in ActivityMaps. So here is my code, it still wont reply with a "testing" SMS, when an "UPDATE" SMS is sent to me.

```
public class IncomingSMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            if (pdus.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
            }
            String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            String message = sb.toString();
            String txtSMS="Testing";
            if (message.startsWith("UPDATE"))
            {

                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                this.abortBroadcast();
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(sender, null, txtSMS, null, null);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest File

```
receiver android:name=".IncomingSMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.android.action.broadcast"/>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: You normally don't call a `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` method directly, and you certainly don't want to do that with SMS. What are you trying to do, exactly? Do you just want to catch incoming messages?

Comment: I want my app to reply an sms when a specific phrase is said with another sms

Comment: And am i doing something wrong? Why are people downvoting when I am just asking a simple question?

Comment: Then you need to register the `BroadcastReceiver`. If you just want to listen for messages while your `MapsActivity` is running, use the `registerReceiver()` method. If you want to get messages even when your app isn't running, then you need to register the Receiver class in the manifest, as shown in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app).

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because a) it wasn't really clear what you're trying to do, and b) there are already hundreds of questions here that show how to receive SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<!-- inside your application tag -->
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSMSReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I want to call onReceive under onCreate(), but im not sure what to put in the brackets of receiver.OnReceive().

Comment: I think you should read the documentation about onReceive to further understand it. Your question is getting uncertain. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive

Comment: I'll explain more in depth, I need to call the onReceive method in the MapsActivity class, the onReceive is actually in the IncomingSMSReceiver class, but when i try to call the class, i got an error because i dont know what to put in the brackets of receiver.onReceive( ); under onCreate form the code above. I can't leave it empty and anything i put inside creates an error

Comment: what's the error? please post it so we can see the cause of your problem.

Comment: Error:(69, 17) error: no suitable method found for onReceive()
method IncomingSMSReceiver.onReceive(Context,Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(Context,Intent) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @RyanPow You do not call `onReceive()`. The system will call it when you get an SMS, if you've properly registered the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @MikeM. was right. Properly declare your BroadcastReceiver in your Manifest file, and the system will call it whenever it receives a broadcast. You don't have to create new instance of it in your MainActivity.

Comment: My edited codes are now in the question, I'm willing to listen to any help you can give

Comment: @sinense I'm able to send an SMS, but the app cant detect the messages at all. So it will never auto reply.

Comment: I used a System.out.println to find where the code got stuck, the code cant get past the if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) statement, even if an SMS is sent