# Toast Not Showing In SMS Receive Android App

Tags: java, android, sms, toast

I'm creating a simple Android application where I'm trying to intercept incoming SMS messages. The problem I am having is that the toast messages from the onReceive isn't showing up. Please help!

Thanks,

Isaiah Thompson

```
public class SMSR extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //Print Message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Received Message Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Get the data (SMS data) bound to intent
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    String str = "";

    if (bundle != null) {
        // Retrieve the SMS Messages received
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        // For every SMS message received
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            // Convert Object array
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // Sender's phone number
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
            // Fetch the text message
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            // Newline <img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/72x72/1f642.png">
            str += "\n";
        }
    }


    //Print Message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Received Message End",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Don't use `Toast` for debugging. Use `Log.d` instead. Also - are you certain that you are receiving the SMS

Comment: There are lots of moving pieces. Check this answer for a detailed guide. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436473/6051131

Comment: I don't think I am receiving SMS messages. When I send a test text, the app doesn't seem to intercept it, however I believe the code above is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         Toast.makeText(context, R.string.sent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436473/6051131

also, make sure your priority (in the manifest file) is less than or equal `2147483647`