# Is it possible to access sms without setting Android default sms app?

Tags: android

I have a question while studying Android.
I am wondering if there is a way to access sms / mms without setting the Android default sms app.
Thank you.

Comment: Read access?  Or write/delete?  The first yes, the second no.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there is a way to access sms / mms without setting
>   the Android default sms app.

If your intention is to just read/receive the SMS then Yes. Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app) for implementation details.

If your intention is to modify (write/delete) SMS then No.

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you for your answer