# How to retrieve/access all sms of a android phone using Python and Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I want to retrieve all sms and show on the display. I did a code using QPython but its not work with kivy, so I need to know code of python which will work with Kivy.

My code which is running on Qpython :

```
import androidhelper as myandroid

    droid = myandroid.Android()
    id1 = droid.smsGetMessages(unreadOnly=False,folder='inbox',attributes=None).result

    for items in id1[0:]:

        inbox_add=str(items.get("address").encode("utf-8"))    

        inbox_sms=str(items.get("body").encode("utf-8"))

        read_sms=str(items.get("read"))

        sms_date=str(items.get("date"))
```

Help me to solve it or suggest me another way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436473/6764079

Answer (score 0):

I believe that code works on QPython because you are using the `sl4a` project.To get the same services on python,using kivy rather,you will need to use [pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

This let's you access the android api then you take that result and use it however you want