# How to receive an SMS?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I wrote an Android SMS Receiver program as follows. The problem is that there is no way to receive a broadcast of SMS. How can I do?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name=".ExampleBroadcastReceiver2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter  android:priority="999" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.telephony.action.DEFAULT_SMS_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.telephony.action.CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED" />

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_EMERGENCY_CB_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_CB_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.cellbroadcastreceiver.START_CONFIG" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SERVICE_CATEGORY_PROGRAM_DATA_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Detailed program link as follows:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1etiXj0DmPwmIx8S1aLeDPqz20XDaiOQy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is your receiver ?

Comment: I think this will helpful <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435354/receiving-sms-on-android-app>